# Angular dynamic filter for array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm trying to create a filtered array with dynamic variables. I create an array which holdes the filter keys, and then I create an filtered array which only should return items that match the keys from my first array.

Array with filter keys:
`$scope.participantArray = ["kti@test.com", "mob@test.com"]`

Code for filtering second array:

```
$scope.items = $scope.items.filter(function (data) {
                            var i = $scope.participantArray.length;
                             while( i-- ) {
                           return  ( data.Title === $scope.participantArray[i] ) 
                        }
```

I'm trying to loop through all keys and apply them to the filtered array. The problem is that it only returns one match. I ahve to instances in my `items` array which match the keys from my first array.

The while loop only returns `mob@test.com`.

Any suggestions on what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in an easier way using `indexOf`:

```
$scope.items.filter(function(item) {
    if($scope.participantArray.indexOf(item.Title) >= 0) {
        return true;
    }
})
```

Comment: Great job! Nice and simple. Will mark as completed as soon as possible.

Comment: Missing ')' in your if statement.

Comment: yup, added that. Also, changed the condition to account for 0th index.